# Using Rails Inflections with `rails generate`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to generate a model called `ClassAttendance`, but Rails keeps naming the migrations `class_attendances`. I've tried correcting this problem by placing the following code the following code in `\config\initializers\inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable "attendance"
end
```

This seems to work fine in the rails console:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.6)
irb(main):001:0> "attendance".pluralize
=> "attendance"
```

Unfortunately, the rails model generator seems to be unaffected:

```
$ rails generate model ClassAttendance 
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20120806201910_create_class_attendances.rb
      create    app/models/class_attendance.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create      spec/models/class_attendance_spec.rb
```

Does it have something to do with this?

```
irb(main):002:0> "class_attendance".pluralize
=> "class_attendances"
```

Or is there some other problem I'm not seeing?

Comment: For now, I'm just doing this as a workaround:

`ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w( attendance class_attendance ClassAttendance)
end`

It's a pretty ugly hack, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the workaround, you need to place it in the `inflections.rb` file in the `config/initializers/`. So your `config/initializers/inflections.rb` would be

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect| 
  inflect.uncountable %w( attendance class_attendance ClassAttendance) 
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is what I need to do. I did just discover a slightly cleaner way of doing that using regular expressions: `inflect.uncountable(/.*attendance.*/i)`. In either case, it works; so I guess I have nothing to complain about.