# Generate model with custom inflector containing spaces in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-generation

I am trying to generate a model and resources using

```
rails g model AreaOfLaw name
```

This creates area_of_laws as the plural version, but I want areas_of_law. As suggested in [How do I override rails naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions) I have added the following to /config/initializers/inflections.rb:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'area of law', 'areas of law'
end
```

This custom inflection doesn't work when running a generator even though it does work in rails console:

```
"area of law".pluralize
=> "areas of law"
```

**How can I make this work for generators?**

Comment: What do you mean by making this "work for generators"?

Comment: @MrYoshiji like the first line above `rails g model AreaOfLaw`

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835428/using-rails-inflections-with-rails-generate

Comment: Thanks @Speed, I added `inflect.uncountable %w(AreaOfLaw area_of_law)` that cuts the 's' from the end given me `area_of_law`, but I'm hoping to get `areas_of_law`.

Comment: and `inflect.irregular`does not work? Hmm, curious. Maybe try opening an issue on the Rails repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do

```
inflect.irregular 'area_of_law', 'areas_of_law'
```

then it works:

```
'AreaOfLaw'.tableize
# => "areas_of_law"
```

---

Might be nicer to have the model named `LawArea` instead though.

Comment: Thanks @AJcodez, the underscores fixed it. What I missed then is that I needed to match the table name which of course, uses underscores.

Comment: Hah, superb, I missed that too.